# символ ' в регулярных выражениях

Tags: php

Не получается избавиться от символа ' . Выдаёт то ромбики со знаками вопроса то код. Уже всё перепробовал .

```
if ( $terms ) {
    $i = 2;
    printf( '<div class="%s">
        <h2 class="text-center">Select one of the functional areas</h2>
        <ul class="clearfix">', esc_attr( $class ) );
      printf( '<li class="'.$activet.'" ><a  href="%s">All categories</a><div class="description">All categories on one page</div></li>', esc_url( site_url() ));

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            $active ='';
            // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
            $term_name = esc_html( $term->name );
            $clean = preg_replace("/[^\w]/", "", $term_name);
            $name = "/\b".$clean."\b/i";
            if (preg_match($name,$link) == true && preg_match($name,$url) == true) {
            $active = 'active-taxonomy';

            } else {
            $active ='';
            } 
            // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
            if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            printf( '<li class="'.esc_html( $term->name ).' '.$active.'" ><a href="%s">%s</a><div class="description">%s</div></li>', esc_url( $term_link ), esc_html( $term->name ),esc_html( $term->description ) );
            if (($i % 3) === 0) {
                echo '<li class="clear">&nbsp;</li>';
            }
            $i++;
        }
    print( '</ul></div>' );
}
```

Если делать вот так:

```
    if ( $terms ) {
    $i = 2;
    printf( '<div class="%s">
        <h2 class="text-center">Select one of the functional areas</h2>
        <ul class="clearfix">', esc_attr( $class ) );
      printf( '<li class="'.$activet.'" ><a  href="%s">All categories</a><div class="description">All categories on one page</div></li>', esc_url( site_url() ));

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            $active ='';
            // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
            $term_name = $term->name;
            $clean = preg_replace("/[^\w]/", "", $term_name);

            $name = "/\b".$clean."\b/i";
            $low = strtolower($name);
            $link = strtolower($term_link);
            if (preg_match($name,$link) == true && preg_match($name,$url) == true) {
            $active = ' active-taxonomy';
            } else {
            $active ='';
            }
            // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
            if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            printf( '<li class="'.$low.$active.'" ><a href="%s">%s</a><div class="description">%s</div></li>', esc_url( $term_link ), esc_html( $term->name ),esc_html( $term->description ) );
            if (($i % 3) === 0) {
                echo '<li class="clear">&nbsp;</li>';
            }
            $i++;
        }
    print( '</ul></div>' );
}
```

То выдает  -  ��hildrensroom   . Я вообще не могу понять в таком случае. Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Может потому что вы производите замену в другой переменной?
попробуйте так:

```
    $h = "Man's horse"; 
    $replace = preg_replace("/[^\w]/", "", $h);
    var_dump($replace);
```

Comment: Да это опечатка .  Не продвинулся с помощью var_dump : string(17) "Сhildren039sroom"  . Проблема в самом регулярном выражении . Не могу понять как указать именно этот символ , чтобы его не было на выводе.

Comment: $h = preg_replace("/[^\w]/",'',$term_name);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/",'',$h);

Comment: @Andrei Sukharev, код из ответа выдаст `string(9) "Manshorse"`. Вы избавились и от одинарной кавычки, и от пробела.

Comment: всё верно. Наверное у меня конфликт функций вордпресса с php. Может посмотрите на код выше - я привёл варианты и результаты.

Comment: @AndreiSukharev так попробуйте такое регулярное выражение [^\w\s] - удалит все кроме букв и пробелов

Comment: пробелы тоже не нужны . Пока вопрос не решен - заменил слова с верхней кавычкой но вопрос открыт.

Comment: Подозреваю что автор работает с кириллическими символами, тогда используйте модификатор `u` для регулярного выражения

Comment: Нет. У меня латиница.

Answer (score 0):

Стринг реплайс не

`str_replace("'","",$h);`